# Cannot Boot Ubuntu from External HDD on Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, external-hdd

Recently I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 on my 150GB external hdd.

I can boot it on my old Windows 7 laptop(Dell) without any problem.

However, I am not able to boot it on my Windows 10 laptop(Fujitsu).
I have tried different solution online, but they didn't work.

I am thinking is there any problem on my installation or it just the problem of my computer.
I want my external hdd able to boot on both Windows 7 and Windows 10, then I can use it at school.

Thank you.

Comment: "I have tried different solution online, but they didn't work." What solutions did you try, and what happened when you tried them?

Comment: Maybe you installed Ubuntu in BIOS mode (in the computer with Windows 7). Your new computer with Windows 10 probably boots in UEFI mode, so you need an installation for UEFI mode. See this link and links from it: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#UEFI